# Creating a vector with cumulative sums after specific indices

Tags: r, math, diff, cumsum

I've got the following problem from my lector:

> Make a vector which for each time `y` takes the value `5` shows the
>   cumulated sum of `x` values from the preceding position where `y` took the
>   value `5`. 1 (Hint: use the commands `cumsum()` and `diff()`.)

I'm not really sure in what format the vector in question is supposed to be formatted, so I propose two functions that give me the two different possible answers I can think of. Furthermore I don't understand in what way I'm supposed to use `diff()` instead I used a for-loop to tackle the problem:

```
# Creates random vectors
x <- round(runif(100,0,10))
y <- round(runif(100,0,10))


# X_,Y_ are arbitrary vectors of length n, and value decides what index from X_ is supposed to be chosen, as formulated in the question it is supposed to be 5.
# index is a vector that stores which entries of Y which has the value "value".

# Gives a vector as (x_1, x_(1+2),..., x_(sum(1,2...,index[1])))
test.cumsum <- function(X_,Y_, value){
  index <- which(Y_ == value)
  for(i in 1:length(index)){
    if(i == 1){
      z <- cumsum(x[1:index[1]])
    }
    if(i == length(index)){
      break 
    }
    else{
      z <- c(z,cumsum(x[(index[i]+1):index[i+1]]))
    }  
  }
  z
}

# Gives a vector as (x_1+x_2...+index[1],x_(index[1]+1)+x_(index[1]+2)+...)
test.sum <- function(X_,Y_, value){ 
  index <- which(Y_ == value)
  for(i in 1:length(index)){
    if(i == 1){
      z <- sum(x[1:index[1]])
    }
    if(i == length(index)){
      break 
    }
    else{
      z <- c(z,sum(x[(index[i]+1):index[i+1]]))
    }  
  }
  z
}
```

Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: `ave(x, cumsum(y == 5), FUN = cumsum)`?

Comment: This is so much simpler. I think it is the correct way to interpret the problem. Thanks!